# Show the whole query in Solr

Tags: solr

I can't manage to get shown all the query when I make a research in Solr.
This is my log4j.properties.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO,CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.apache=DEBUG,CONSOLE
#log4j.logger.CONTENT=INFO,CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %t%n[%p]: %m%n
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change my schema.xlm

```
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="echoParams">all</str>
<int name="rows">10</int>
<str name="fl">*</str>
<str name="version">2.1</str>
</lst>
```